# Skipping over results with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to filter out results form a API and want to exclude certain results form showing up for example:

```
LEGACY-NA-XboxOfficialServer219
EU-PVP-XboxOfficial-TheIslanSmallTribes219
EU-PVP-XboxOfficial-TheIsland219
```

I want the last result.  So I put a Negative look behind for the smalltribes part but now need something to identify if its LEGACY or not and to skip that result if it is

What i have so far:

```
re.search(r"[a-zA-Z](?<!SmallTribes)" + str(number) + r"$", x['Name']):
```

Im trying to get it to only display

```
EU-PVP-XboxOfficial-TheIsland219
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show how exactly the response looks from the API?You mentioned that you want the last result, isn't that `EU-PVP-XboxOfficial-TheIsland219`? Please share expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?!LEGACY).*[a-zA-Z](?<!SmallTribes)219$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xnbicf/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!LEGACY)` - no `LEGACY` substring at the start is allowed
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `[a-zA-Z]` - a letter
- `(?<!SmallTribes)` - no `SmallTribes` substring right before...
- `219$` - the `219` number at the end of the string.

In Python:

```
re.search(r"^(?!LEGACY).*[a-zA-Z](?<!SmallTribes){}$".format(number), x['Name']):
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/2gfC0x):

```
import re
strs = ['LEGACY-NA-XboxOfficialServer219',
'EU-PVP-XboxOfficial-TheIslanSmallTribes219',
'EU-PVP-XboxOfficial-TheIsland219']
number = 219
rx = re.compile(r"^(?!LEGACY).*[a-zA-Z](?<!SmallTribes){}$".format(number))
for s in strs:
    if re.search(rx, s):
        print(s)
# => EU-PVP-XboxOfficial-TheIsland219
```